# ansible cannot determine host os

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am running ansible version 6.1.0.
Here is a snippet of my hosts.yml file:

```
pi1:
  vars:
  hosts:
    192.168.2.31:
```

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- name: Maintain Pi Cluster
  hosts: piCluster
  connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
  gather_facts: true
  remote_user: don
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Ping the Servers
      connection: local
      ansible.builtin.ping:

    - name: Upgrade installed APT Packages
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        upgrade: yes
        update_cache: yes
```

I can ping the host:

```
TASK [Ping the Servers] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.2.31]
```

But I cannot do anything on the host like apt-get update:

```
TASK [Upgrade installed APT Packages] **************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.2.31]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unable to automatically determine host network os. Please manually configure ansible_network_os value for this host"}
```

I can ssh to the host:

```
$ ssh don@192.168.2.31
Linux pi1 5.15.32-v8+ #1538 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 31 19:40:39 BST 2022 aarch64
...
blah, blah
...
don@pi1:~ $
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What connection plugin are you using? Can you add the code of your playbook in your question?

Comment: added the playbook.  for ping, the connection is local.  for apt-get, i don't list a connection.  is that the issue?

Comment: Any reason to explicitly use `connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli`? (`ssh` **is** the default if none set) According to documentation, `ansible_network_os` is mandatory when using this connection plugin: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_best_practices_2.5.html#common-inventory-variables Also: why explicitly using another connection plugin for the `ping`?

Comment: Don't mess with the connection in order to do something from the controller, rather [`delegate_to: localhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was ansible_connection was not set, and I though ssh was the default.

I added the following to my hosts.yaml file:

```
piCluster:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: ssh
  children:
...
```

I tried to add it to the ansible.cfg file, but that did not help.

Comment: As the connection plugin is overwritten in the play to `ansible.netcommon.network_cli`, setting it in the inventory has no effect. If you want to use `ssh`, just remove the `connection` in the play.